# li absolute position in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having an issue with IE positioning for li items `position:absolute;` . The structure works fine in all other browsers like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-nav">
     <ul class="nav">
       <a href="#">
         <li id="an-item">Hi</li>
       </a>
     <ul>
 </div>
<div>
```

All parent containers are `position:relative` and work fine in other browsers. In IE with this format the items start the positioning relative to outside the container. The only way I got it to be right is adding `position:absolute;` to the `<a>` tag. When I do this though it throws off all the other browsers. Any way to fix this? Should I use conditional CSS or is that not a standard anymore?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The only valid child of a `ol` or `ul` is an `li` - you can't have an `a` as a child

Comment: Oh man. I didnt even think of that. Started working with someone else's project and it overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

you can't put an `anchor tag` inside a `ul` IE doesn't allow that other browser are way friendly with some invalid HTML structure but not the case with IE  what you can do is the following :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-nav">
     <ul class="nav">

         <li id="an-item"><a href="#">Hi</a></li>

     <ul>
 </div>
<div>
```

put  your `anchor tag` inside the `li`